# How to apply notification tap action to specific activity in android?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-manifest

Android: How to bind Notification action to activity Dynamically in Android Manifest file?

Specially for fire-base integration.
Please give suggestion.Thank you

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: from api i get different case of notification to intent with diifferent activity. When app is open work fine but app in background it's not works

Comment: If, I understood the problem correctly, you'll have to add intent filter to all those activities, which needs to be opened on the arrival of the notification. you can have an activity url in your notification payload, and use it in the Receiver, to start the intent with that action.

Comment: ok means from api side use 'click_action'. suggested by fire-base console??

Comment: Yeah, or you can send as a data payload, and access it from the data

Comment: Ohhhh.. Thank you.. It's works for me

Comment: I will add the same as answer, so that others may find it easy to view...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128505/discussion-between-abdul-rahman-k-and-pradip-kachhadiya).

Answer (score 5):

*Recive Custom Message in Notification And According to KeyWork True Or false Or Your Specific Word go to Activity*
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
Bitmap bitmap;

 /**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    //
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
    //You can change as per the requirement.

    //message will contain the Push Message
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
    //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
    String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened. 
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened. 
    String TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");

    //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);

    sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFlase);

}


/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 */

private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.firebase_icon)
            .setContentTitle(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

This is AnotherActivity

```
    // If a notification message is tapped, any data accompanying the notification
    // message is available in the intent extras. In this project the launcher
    // intent is fired when the notification is tapped, so any accompanying data would
    // be handled here. If you want a different intent fired, set the click_action
    // field of the notification message to the desired intent. The launcher intent
    // is used when no click_action is specified.
    //
    // Handle possible data accompanying notification message.
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);

            if (key.equals("AnotherActivity") && value.equals("True")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        }
    }
```

*This is The Data*

```
{ "data": {
    "image": "https://ibin.co/2t1lLdpfS06F.png",
    "message": "Firebase Push Message Using API"
    "AnotherActivity": "True"
  },
  "to" : "f25gYF3***********************HLI"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve the functionality of opening an activity, upon receiving of notification, that activity should be given `intent-filter` in manifest, to listen for an action.

In the Notification, along with the payload, the action which the activity listens for, should be sent. In the Receiver, an `Intent` with such an action can be fired, which opens the activity, Even if app is in backgroud or closed.